# Get symbol for ParameterSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to write a little Roslyn util to rename variables/members/parameters in the project. It seems the best course of action is Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync method. In order to use it, I need a solution and semantic symbol. So far I'm having hard time getting this information. Here's what I tried so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Rename;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace PlayCodeAnalysis
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var solutionPath = @"D:\Development\lams\src\Lams.sln";
      var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
      var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

      var doc = solution.Projects.First().Documents.First();
      var model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
      var syntax = doc.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;

      var s = syntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<ParameterSyntax>().ToList();
      var symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(s[0]).Symbol;

      //Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(solution,)

    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `symbol` ends up being empty, I'm not sure why. `s` resolves correctly to a list of all parameters in the file, but I can't convert it to a symbol to pass into the renamer.

The document that is being targeted in this particular case looks like this, and the `s[0]` in this case ends up being `inCollection`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace System.Linq
{
  public static class AsyncEnumerable
  {
    public static async Task<ILookup<TKey, T>> ToLookupAsync<T, TKey>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> inCollection, Func<T, TKey> inKeySelector)
    {
      return (await inCollection.ConfigureAwait(false)).ToLookup(inKeySelector);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance at the Roslyn source, you may have to use `GetDeclaredSymbol` instead of `GetSymbolInfo` on the `ParameterSyntax`.

Comment: Correct. Use `GetDeclaredSymbol` for symbols in a declaring context (e.g. where it is defined). There are some that can be both but that's more of an edgecase.